# Is there a way to prevent the listview from scrolling to its top position when its adapter's data is changed?

Tags: android

I'm having a bit of trouble preserving the scroll position of a list view when changing it's adapter's data.

What I'm currently doing is to create a custom ArrayAdapter (with an overridden getView method) in the `onCreate` of a ListFragment, and then assign it to its list:

```
mListAdapter = new CustomListAdapter(getActivity());
mListAdapter.setNotifyOnChange(false);
setListAdapter(mListAdapter);
```

Then, when I receive new data from a loader that fetches everything periodically, I do this in  its `onLoadFinished` callback:

```
mListAdapter.clear();
mListAdapter.addAll(data.items);
mListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

The problem is, calling `clear()` resets the listview's scroll position. Removing that call preserves the position, but it obviously leaves the old items in the list.

What is the proper way to do this?

Comment: You can get the position before and then set the position back.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

As you pointed out yourself, the call to 'clear()' causes the position to be reset to the top.

Fiddling with scroll-position, etc. is a bit of a hack to get this working.

If your CustomListAdapter subclasses from ArrayAdapter, this could be the issue:

The call to clear(), calls 'notifyDataSetChanged()'. You can prevent this:

```
mListAdapter.setNotifyOnChange(false); // Prevents 'clear()' from clearing/resetting the listview
mListAdapter.clear();
mListAdapter.addAll(data.items);
// note that a call to notifyDataSetChanged() implicitly sets the setNotifyOnChange back to 'true'!
// That's why the call 'setNotifyOnChange(false) should be called first every time (see call before 'clear()').
mListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

I haven't tried this myself, but try it :)

Comment: I have turned off the notifyonchange when I created the list adapter (sorry for not mentioning it in my original post). I didn't know that it would be turned back on when I manually notify though. I will need to test this.

Comment: That's the answer. Thanks, much better than the "scroll-after-updating" hacks :) Too bad (this weird, imho) behaviour isn't documented.

Comment: where i have to use this code ? please let me know this

Comment: How is this done in c#?  It seems this is Java?  Can't find the same methods in c#.

Answer (score 6):

Check out: [Maintain/Save/Restore scroll position when returning to a ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3014089/maintain-save-restore-scroll-position-when-returning-to-a-listview)

Use this to save the position in the ListView before you call .clear(), .addAll(), and . notifyDataSetChanged().

```
int index = mList.getFirstVisiblePosition();
View v = mList.getChildAt(0);
int top = (v == null) ? 0 : v.getTop();
```

After updating the ListView adapter, the Listview's items will be changed and then set the new position:

```
mList.setSelectionFromTop(index, top);
```

Basically you can save you position and scroll back to it, save the ListView state or the entire application state.

Other helpful links:

Save Position:
[How to save and restore ListView position in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7167487/how-to-save-and-restore-listview-position-in-android)

Save State:
[Android ListView y position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5878421/android-listview-y-position)

Regards,

Please let me know if this helps!

Comment: This kind of works, but it feels a bit hacky. Mostly because, even though the listview itself doesn't move, the scrollbar flashes whenever the update occurs. With updates every second or so, it looks like a giant grey blinking light. I could hide the scrollbar itself, but it is quite useful.

Comment: This question has been answered many times on here. I was simply giving one example :)

Comment: I'll add this to your answer in order to fix my scrollbar blink: `mList.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false)` at the beginning and `mList.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(true)` at the end. Though I'm really hoping for something a bit less hackish :)

Comment: Ok, check the links. That is really the only 3 solutions possible.

Answer (score 0):

There is one more use-case I came across recently (Android 8.1) - caused by bug in Android code. If I use mouse-wheel to scroll list view - consecutive `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` resets scroll position to zero. Use this workaround until bug gets fixed in Android

```
        listView.onTouchModeChanged(true); // workaround
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

More details is here: https://issuetracker.google.com/u/1/issues/130103876

Answer (score -1):

In your Expandable/List Adapter, put this method

```
public void refresh(List<MyDataClass> dataList) {
    mDataList.clear();
    mDataList.addAll(events);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

And from your activity, where you want to update the list, put this code

```
if (mDataListView.getAdapter() == null) {
    MyDataAdapter myDataAdapter = new MyDataAdapter(mContext, dataList);
    mDataListView.setAdapter(myDataAdapter);
} else {
    ((MyDataAdapter)mDataListView.getAdapter()).refresh(dataList);
}
```

> In case of **Expandable List View**, you will use
>   **mDataListView.getExpandableListAdapter()** instead of
>   **mDataListView.getAdapter()**