# Scroll position jumps to previous list items while scrolling up in Custom Listview

Tags: java, android, listview, scroll

I have an activity containing a listview. The list fetches more data when the user scrolls to the bottom of the listview. The scrolling is smooth when the user scrolls downwards. But, when the user scrolls upwards, the listview tends to jump its visible items by one or two.

**The class:**

```
public class ListViewActivity extends Activity implements OnScrollListener {

    int id = 0;
    List<String> dataParse = new ArrayList<String>();
    LazyAdapter adapter;
    ListView listView;
    List<RichPost> richArrayList = new ArrayList<RichPost>();

    private int currentScrollState;
    private int currentVisibleItemCount;
    private int skipParam = 0;
    private boolean flag_loading = false;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_post_list_list);

        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        // Need to create the adapter constructor
        listView.setOnScrollListener(this);
        adapter = new LazyAdapter(PostListActivity.this, dataParse, richArrayList);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        setStory();

    }

    public void setStory() {

        // Pull data from Parse
        HashMap<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        params.put("userid", ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getObjectId());
        params.put("skip", skipParam);

        ParseCloud.callFunctionInBackground("studentsPosts", params, new FunctionCallback<List<List<ParseObject>>>() {
            @Override
            public void done(List<List<ParseObject>> data, com.parse.ParseException arg1) {
                if (data == null) {

                } else {
                    Log.e("size ", "RUNNING Size :   " + data.size());

                    if (data.size() > 0) {
                        flag_loading = false;
                        for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++) {
                            RichPost rc = new RichPost();
                            if (data.get(0).get(0).get("htmlContent") != null) {
                                // Switch i to 1 to force just 1 additon.

                                dataParse.add(data.get(i).get(0).getString("htmlContent"));
                                rc.setHtmlCode(data.get(i).get(0).getString("htmlContent"));
                                Log.i("Calling notifiyDataSetchanged", "now");


                            }
                            if(data.get(i).get(0).get("photos") != null){

                                List<ParseFile> pFileList;
                                pFileList = (List<ParseFile>) data.get(i).get(0).get("photos");


                                rc.setPhotosArray(pFileList);


                            }
                            if(data.get(i).get(0).getParseFile("photo") != null){
                                //Time to retrieve the photo
                                ParseFile getParseFile;
                                getParseFile = (ParseFile) data.get(i).get(0).get("photo");
                                //ParseFile getParseFile = ParseFile.this.getDataInBackground(data.get(i).get(0).getParseFile("photo"));
                                rc.setPhoto(getParseFile);
                            }

                            richArrayList.add(rc);
                            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        }
                    }
                }

            }

        });

    }

    @Override
    public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
        this.currentScrollState = scrollState;
        this.isScrollCompleted();
    }

    private void isScrollCompleted() {
        if (this.currentVisibleItemCount >= 5 && this.currentScrollState == SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {


        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
        this.currentVisibleItemCount = visibleItemCount;

        Log.e("firstVisibleItem", ""+firstVisibleItem);
        Log.e("visibleItemCount", ""+visibleItemCount);
        Log.e("totalItemCount", ""+totalItemCount);
        if (firstVisibleItem + visibleItemCount == totalItemCount && totalItemCount != 0) {
            if (flag_loading == false) {
                flag_loading = true;
                Log.d("IN ON SCROLL", "NOW: " + skipParam);
                skipParam = skipParam + 10; 
                setStory();
            }

        }
    }

}
```

Where am I going wrong? Why is the upward scroll getting affected?

Comment: in xml where you declare listview, do you use layout_height="wrap_content" or layout_height="0dip" + weight = 1? Difference is important as visibleItem count will be equal to totalItemCount in first case, and thus it will affect all your computation

Comment: result is same even after making the alterations

Comment: same issue here... any idea?

Comment: Hey, have you solved this?