# After setData into an adapter the view move up

Tags: android, listview, listview-adapter

In my adapter I have a method to set information:

```
   public void setData(List<ListItem> dataList) {
        this.listItems = dataList;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

But after I call this method, the data is refreshed and my View move up. I don't want this behavior, because if someone is changing something in the end of the page, the focus is lost.

There is any way to set data from an adapter and don't lose the focus?

Answer (score 0):

You must call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` from the UI thread. May be [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17695594/notifydatasetchanged-makes-the-list-refresh-and-scroll-jumps-back-to-the-top) & [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8276128/retaining-position-in-listview-after-calling-notifydatasetchanged) SO posts can help you.