# Prevent android studio from jumping up after every change in scroll layout?

Tags: android-studio

It's super frustrating. After every change in the layout inside a scroll layout, the scroll jumps all the way to the top. is there a way to prevent it? Having to scroll down every time is a major flaw in the work flow

Comment: Possible duplicate of [notifyDataSetChanged() makes the list refresh and scroll jumps back to the top](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17695594/notifydatasetchanged-makes-the-list-refresh-and-scroll-jumps-back-to-the-top)

Comment: possible of duplicate 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17695594/notifydatasetchanged-makes-the-list-refresh-and-scroll-jumps-back-to-the-top

Comment: It is not a duplicate of the questions you've attached. I have no problem at run time. My problem is while working at studio, the layout keeps jumping up.

Comment: So why you want to prevent from refreshing in the UI inspector ??

Comment: I have no problem with refreshing, but if I edit an element at the bottom of the scroll view, I don't need it to scroll all the way to the top, because then I just need to scroll all the way down again to look at it. If I'm not sure about the change and want to try different changes, having to scroll all the way down every time wastes so much time. I think maybe its a bug, I hope they'll fix it.