# How to change single item in recycler view without screen reload?

Tags: java, android

I have Recycler View with a lot of items in. What I want to do is to change the text in TextView inside item that was clicked. I did it in that way:

```
        wordList.set(position, newWord);
        MyProgressActivityAdapter newAdapter = new MyProgressActivityAdapter(wordList, this);
        newAdapter.notifyItemChanged(position);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(newAdapter);
```

And everything works fine except of the fact that the screen goes to the top every time I click item. What can I do to avoid that?

Comment: Is this code inside the onItemClickListener? From the code, it looks like you're initializing a new adapter... You probably don't want to be initializing a whole new adapter every time you change one item. `notifyItemChanged(position)` on the old adapter should be all that you need to do.

Comment: You're right, I changed my code, but even now screen goes to the top every time I click on single item.

Comment: You can try running on the UI thread, as seen by this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/17696214/1421014

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the payload version of `notifyItemChanged`, here is a simple example for you to get the hang of it:

```
adapter.notifyItemChanged(position, "updateText");
```

And then in your `RecyclerAdapter` override the payload version of `onBindViewHolder`:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull List payloads) {
    if (payloads.isEmpty()) onBindViewHolder(holder, position);
    else if ("updateText".equals(payloads.get(0))) {
        if (holder instanceof YourViewHolder) {
            ((YourViewHolder) holder).textView.setText(dataProvider.get(position).getNewText());
        }
    }
}
```

Note that this approach prevents `RecyclerView` from *creating a new `ViewHolder`* and then binding your data, so you should just call the `notifyItemChanged` without resetting the adapter and so.

Answer (score 0):

`notifyItemChanged(position)` should work if you handle it correctly. Try to handle this inside `onBindViewHolder` like below:

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerHolder, position: Int) {
    holder.itemView.text_view.text = items[position]

    holder.itemView.button.setOnClickListener {
        items[position] = "New Text"
        notifyItemChanged(position)
    }
}
```